# Can't compile gegl (gimp) on PPC Leopard

Tags: dsym, gegl

I compile gegl-0.2.0 (needed to compile gimp-2.8) on PowerPC Mac Leopard 10.5.4.

All other programs such as glib-2.38.2, intltool-0.50.2 and babl which are necessary to compile gimp have been compiled fine.

I have this kind of errors while compiling gegl:

```
GEGL-geglmodule.c-Message: Module '../../operations/common/.libs/layer.so.dSYM
/Contents/Resources/DWARF/layer.so' load error: dlopen(../../operations/common
/.libs/layer.so.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/layer.so, 10): no suitable image found.
Did find
../../operations/common/.libs/layer.so.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/layer.so: can't map
```

I get this for each .so file produced by gegl, such as box-blur.so, brightness-contrast.so, motion-blur.so, contrast-curve.so, etc. Also I get this kind of errors for each of those .so files:

```
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch ppc)
  CC      motion-blur.c
  CCLD    motion-blur.la
```

The env variables are:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include:/usr/include -fno-inline"
export LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib
export CFLAGS="-Wno-long-double -arch ppc -fno-inline"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/X11/lib
```

If I remove the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, an error like "libjpeg.dylib,libpng.dylib,libtiff.dylib and libgl.dylib can't be found" comes up.

The compiler I use is (Apple) gcc-3.3, but the same errors come up if I use gcc-4.0 or gcc-4.2. I don't use XCode for anything.

What's the basic problem here and how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I discovered that the only way to prevent this error from happening was to prevent CC from producing dsym code. Surely it 's not so simple as it's in Xcode. It turned out that I had to edit the Makefile. There at the 188th line was:
DSYMUTIL = 'dsymutil'
I made it: 
DSYMUTIL= ''
and that prevented dsym from being generated and I finally got rid of that error.
But after that I I got another error, about some "xxx.xml" file. To solve it, I added this to configure command:
./configure --disable-docs

Then I got the gegl perfectly compiled. FYI.